# python3 access bs4 element's lines with index

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a bs4 object and select a part of it using `findAll` and `find_next_sibling`. From this part which I call "sibling" I access every single line with a for loop like this:

```
for cursor in sibling:
    index = sibling.index(cursor)
    print(index)          # works until here
    next_cursor = sibling[index+1]
    print(next_cursor)    # breaks with KeyError
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I understand your situation, I can suggest an easier way of going about this.

Suppose you have HTML like this.

```
<span id="first">I'm first</span>
<span>first sibling</span>
<span>second sibling</span>
<span>third sibling</span>
<span>fourth sibling</span>
<span>fifth sibling</span>
```

Then you can find the first `span` element and then identify all of its siblings using code like this.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> first = soup.select('#first')
>>> first
[<span id="first">I'm first</span>]
```

This line is intended merely to display what the `findNextSiblings` method gives you.

```
>>> first[0].findNextSiblings()
[<span>first sibling</span>, <span>second sibling</span>, <span>third sibling</span>, <span>fourth sibling</span>, <span>fifth sibling</span>]
```

This means that, once you have a pointer to the first sibling you can get all of the others with a single `for` statement.

```
>>> for sib in first[0].findNextSiblings():
...     sib.text
... 
'first sibling'
'second sibling'
'third sibling'
'fourth sibling'
'fifth sibling'
```

Another method, `fetchNextSiblings` provides the same results as the one used above.

```
>>> first[0].fetchNextSiblings()
[<span>first sibling</span>, <span>second sibling</span>, <span>third sibling</span>, <span>fourth sibling</span>, <span>fifth sibling</span>]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I could solve my problem by accessing sibling[index+2] instead of index+1. The content was nested in <br/> brackets and I accessed those brackets when I used index+1.

Comment: You're welcome. I answered in this way because I thought you might find it useful and I couldn't tell what exact problem you were battling.

Comment: Actually I did not realize those <br/> brackets made up a line of their own. I thought they are part of the lines I was looking at.

Comment: @Ollie: Maybe you should stop thinking in lines because BeatifulSoup does not operate on lines but on an object tree.

Answer (score 0):

The sibling you have created with BeautifulSoup cannot be read line by line like this.

The sibling is of the type bs4.element.Tag. If you want to read it line by line you must convert it to a string and then call `.splitlines()` on it.

Like this:

```
for line in str(sibling).splitlines():
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Splitting lines is not necessary because the for loop is accessing the content line by line.